# Can i django-paypal signals add in views?

Tags: python, django, paypal, django-paypal

I add in my views this code :

```
from paypal.standard.ipn.signals import payment_was_successful

def updateuser(sender, **kwargs):
    userid = request.session['userid']
    acc = accounts.objects.get(twitterid=userid)
    acc.credit=200
    acc.save()

payment_was_successful.connect(updateuser)
```

I am add models.py and views.py don't work ,what can i make ?

Github project : https://github.com/dcramer/django-paypal

Answer (score 0):

`request` is not defined in function `updatuser`.

You **cannot** get it from kwargs like this:

```
def updateuser(sender, **kwargs):
    request = kwargs['request']
```

You can add a breakpoint (or logger) in the function to see if it is fired:

```
def updateuser(sender, **kwargs):
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```